# Angular 1.4: Render HTML in variable

Tags: html, angular, laravel

I have the following `Angular` code:

```
<tr dir-paginate="item in file.messages | orderBy: orderByField: orderByReversed | itemsPerPage: 10: 'fileMessages'" pagination-id="fileMessages">
     <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.created_at }}</td>
     <td><span data-ng-class="['label', 'label-' + item.type]">{{ item.type }}</span></td>
     <td>{{ item.message }}</td>
</tr>
```

Now the `item.message` contains some `html` which is coming from back end of the application which is in `Laravel`. How to render the `html` in `Angular`? I have tried `ng-bind-html` but to no avail. Any solutions or alternate to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of angular, you can use :

```
<td [innerHTML]="item.message"></td>
```

Angular will sanitize your content (remove  for example) for security purposes.

Comment: My angular version is 1.4. I tried it but didn't work.